# reverse list with inputData

Tags: c#, reverse

I want to reverse an array with `console.ReadLine()`, but I'm stuck.
Here is statement of problem.

Give an array of 10 natural numbers. Displays the numbers in the string in reverse order.

The numbers in the string are given on a single line and are separated by a space. The application will display the numbers on a single line, separated by a space between them.

Example:

For input data:

`1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`

The console will display:

`10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1`

here is my code:

```
string number = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

List<string> originalList = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
{
    originalList.Add(number);
}
foreach (string item in originalList)
{
    Console.Write(item + " ");
}
originalList.Reverse();

foreach (string item in originalList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item + " ");
}
Console.WriteLine();
```

Comment: Possible only with a `string.Split (' ')` otherwise a *for* or *while* loop on string characters

Answer (score 0):

> The numbers in the string are given on a single line and are separated by a space.

The following code is incorrect because `Console.ReadLine` does not stop reading when it encounters whitespace. It will consume the entire input as one entry in `originalList`.

```
string number = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

List<string> originalList = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
{
    originalList.Add(number);
}

// originalList is now [ "1 2 3..." ];
```

Instead, you should look at [`String.Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-5.0).

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();

List<string> originalList = input.Split(' ').ToList();

// originalList is now [ "1", "2", "3", ... ];
```

You can now use `List.Reverse` and [`String.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-5.0) to get your output.

```
originalList.Reverse();

string output = string.Join(' ', originalList);

Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Need either `string.Split (' ')` or a `for` loop or a `while` loop

Using `string.Split (' ')`

```
string [] splitArray = number.Split (' ');
for (int i = 0; i < splitArray.Length; i++)
{
    originalList.Add(splitArray [i]);
}
//rest of the code would be same
```

`For` loop

```
String readvalues="";
for (int i=0;i <number.Length;i++)
{
    if (i==number Length-1)
    {
        readvalues += number [i];
    }
    if (number[i]==" " || i==number.Length-1)
    {
        originalList.Add (readvalues);
        readvalues="";
    }
    else
    {
        readvalues += number [i];
    }
}
//rest of the code would be same
```

`While` loop

```
int index=0;
String readvalues="";
while (index < number.Length)
{
    if (index==number.Length-1)
    {
        readvalues += number [index];
    }
    if (number[index]==" " ||index==number.Length-1)
    {
        originalList.Add (readvalues);
        readvalues="";
    }
    else
    {
        readvalues += number [index];
    }
    index++;
}
//rest of the code would be same
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try *querying* the initial string with a help of *Linq* ([Reverse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.reverse?view=net-5.0)):

- [Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-5.0#System_String_Split_System_Char_System_StringSplitOptions_) string into items
- [Reverse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.reverse?view=net-5.0) these items
- [Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-5.0#System_String_Join_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_String__) items back into string

**Code:**

```
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  // For Test (comment it out for release)
  string source = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10";

  // Uncomment for release 
  // string source = Console.ReadLine();

  string result = string.Join(" ", source
    .Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Reverse());

  Console.WriteLine(result);
```

**Outcome:**

```
  10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, I have a solution for you, what you exactly ask for. Please check the code and let me know =>

```
void Test()
{
        string number = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
        List<string> originalList = new List<string>();

        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(number) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(number) )
        {
            originalList=number.Split(" ").ToList();
            originalList.Reverse();
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", originalList));
        } 
}
```

**Note :** Use those three namespaces `using System;`,`using System.Linq;`,`using System.Collections.Generic;`